# How to use "concept" to constraint typeinterface in C++

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I tried to use concept to constraint type interface, and get complie time polymorphic, but my code can not compiled.

my code just like below:

```cpp
#include<concepts>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

template<typename T>
concept Addable = requires(T a, T b) {
    { a + b } -> std::convertible_to<T>;
};

template<typename T, typename V>
concept Accumulatable =
requires(T t, const V & v)
{
    t.acc(v);
    requires Addable<V>;
};

struct SumAccumulator2 {
    int sum = 0;
    SumAccumulator2& acc(const int& other) {
        sum += other;
        return *this;
    }
};


template<Accumulatable T, Addable V>
auto accumulate(std::vector<V>& v) -> V
{
    T sum_acc;
    std::ranges::for_each(v, [&sum_acc](const auto& e) { sum_acc.acc(e); });
    std::cout << "result is:    " << sum_acc.sum << "\n"; //log
    return sum_acc.sum;
}


void concept_crtp_main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

    SumAccumulator2 sum2;

    accumulate<SumAccumulator2, int>(vec);
}
```

I compiled codes in Visual Studio 2019 which produces error message:

```
  error C2672: 'accumulate': no matching overloaded function found
  error C7602: 'accumulate': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

Comment: You need to tell `Accumulatable` what to accumulate. Not really familiar with these kind of concepts but if you switch `V` and `T` to `Addable V, Accumulatable<V> T` and then swap the template parameters when calling `accumulate`, this seems to fix the issue (at least for clang).

Answer (score 1):

The `Accumulatable` concept constrains the two template parameters `T` and `V`, and declaring `Accumulatable T` is insufficient because the compiler does not know what `V` is.

You can check both types using the `requires`-clause

```
template<class T, Addable V>
  requires Accumulatable<T, V>
auto accumulate(std::vector<V>& v) -> V {
  T sum_acc;
  std::ranges::for_each(v, [&sum_acc](const auto& e) { sum_acc.acc(e); });
  std::cout << "result is:    " << sum_acc.sum << "\n"; //log
  return sum_acc.sum;
}
```

In addition, there is no need to explicitly specify the type of `V`, because the compiler will automatically deduce it, you can just write

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
SumAccumulator2 sum2;
accumulate<SumAccumulator2/*, int*/>(vec);
```